# Create a language selector with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML and a XSLT. I am supposed to produce an PDF with the content from the XML file.

In the XML there is a  element that should be used to select which language the output should be.

Then I want to have all three different languages listed in the xsl as variables, and use the value from my xml to chose which one to use.

So in my xsl:
    Headline in english
    Headline in french
    Headline in spanish

```
<xsl:variable name="en_text">Text in english</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="fr_text">Text in french</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="dk_text">Text in spanish</xsl:variable>
```

And in my XML:

```
<Language>en</Language>
...
```

In my xsl I would like to concat the value from Language element in the XML with the postfix in the xsl-file. So I can write something like:

```
<block><xsl:value-of select="(value from Language element in xml> + _head")</xsl:value-        of></block>
```

Output should then be the value of the variable $en_head.

Thanks for any reply on this case.

Answer (score 3):

XML has the `xml:lang` attribute standardized and specified to mark up the language and XSLT/XPath support that by using the `lang` function http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-lang.

Therefore I would strongly suggest to use that mechanism instead of building your own.

With XSLT 2.0 you can easily define

```
<xsl:variable name="my-text">
  <list>
    <text xml:lang="en">Text in English</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">Texte en français</text>
    <text xml:lang="es">Texto en español</text>
  </list>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:template match="Foo">
  <block><xsl:value-of select="$my-text/list/text[lang(current()/Language)]"/></block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I get this error: ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'nodeSet' is not a valid object reference.'      Could it be something wrong with my stylesheet?

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or the one in IBM's websphere XML software package? And do you get that error with my suggestion made above? It doesn't use a `nodeSet` function. If you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor then as MiMo has pointed out you need to use an extension function on the variable content e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($my-text)/list/text[lang(current()/Language)]" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>`. The URL used by MiMo is not supported by Java XSLT processors, it is one to be used with Microsoft's MSXML or XslTransform.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like Martin suggested even in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="my-text">
    <text xml:lang="en">Text in English</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">Texte en français</text>
    <text xml:lang="es">Texto en español</text>
  </xsl:variable>  

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="language" select="Language"/>
    <block>
      <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($my-text)/text[lang($language)]"/>
    </block>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`msxsl:node-set` is a Microsoft-specific function to convert XML fragments to node sets, but there are equivalent functions in other XSLT 1.0 processors.